# At what size does Mailbox Database start to suffer issues?

Tags: exchange-2013, mailbox

I have 5 Mailbox Databases in Exchange 2013 Standard.
As I have reached my limit of databases that can be mounted at the same time I cannot just add another should I experience any issues.

As with any database the larger it gets, the slower it performs.
Does anyone know what size a Mailbox Database can get before it starts experiencing significant issues?

I currently have one at 208.6GB, another at 180.4GB and the others are at 30-45GB's in size. The 200GB no longer has any new Mailbox's added to it.

I know migration is relatively easy but its the process to reclaim the white space back to the system drive that can take up the time, so before I put in time to resolve this I want to know if it is going to be worth it or if the database's are perfectly fine being that size.

Comment: The mailbox database size limit in Exchange Server 2013 Standard Edition is 1TB. It's doubtful that your performance issues are a result of your databases. They're not near the size where you'd see performance issues because of the size. If you're having performance issues, they're due to other factors. Have you analyzed your hardware performance?

Comment: We not had any noticeable performance issues yet. I'm looking to see if there is a limit that I should be looking watching out for. Because we have hit the limit of 5 mailboxes, I am conscious that I can't just make a new one to take on any load and that that the ones we have are now just going to grow.

Comment: Why did you create so many mailbox databases?

Comment: They were what was already in place when I started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default database size limit for Exchange Server 2013 Standard Edition is 1,024 gigabytes (GB). This information is mentioned in a similar [case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4bf8a4b-5422-4daa-bfef-639bc0ee94f0/exchange-2013-standard-vs-enterprise?forum=exchangesvrgeneral) for your reference.

If you are afraid that the mailbox databases experience significant issues, you can set the value of “issue warning at (GB) “ in the mailbox database. To specify the storage limit, select the check box, and then specify in gigabytes (GB) how much content can be stored in the mailbox before a warning email message is sent to the
mailbox users. You can enter a value from 0 through 2,097,151 megabytes (MB) (2.0 terabytes). Automatically warn mailbox users that their mailbox is approaching its storage limit.

In EAC, servers—>databases-->limits.Or you can use shell to configure it. For more details:[Set-MailboxDatabase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailbox-databases-and-servers/set-mailboxdatabase?view=exchange-ps#parameters)